# Roman Numbers in Java

Tags: java, roman-numerals

## The Problem

I wanted to create a program that is able to convert roman numbers to arabic numbers and vice versa.

Roman numerals consist of the following symbols:

```
| Symbol | I | V | X  | L  | C   | D   | M    |
|--------|---|---|----|----|-----|-----|------|
| Value  | 1 | 5 | 10 | 50 | 100 | 500 | 1000 |
```

One of the fundamental rules of roman numbers says that it is not possible to use the same symbol more than three times in a row.
So it is possible to write III = 3, but it is not possible to write IIII = 4.

To write these kind of numbers, you can use the following so called subtractive notation:
If a symbol is in front of another, whose value is greater than the value of the first symbol, than the the first value is subtracted from the second value.

For example: IV = 4, XL = 40, but for example VI = 6 and not -4.

## The Solution

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RomanNumbers {

    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int decision = getInput();

        if(decision == 1) {
            String number = getRoman();
            System.out.println(romanToArabic(number));
        }
        else {
            int number = getInt();
            System.out.println(arabicToRoman(number));
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static int romanToArabic(String number) {
        if(!number.matches("[IVXLCDM]+") || number.equals("") || number == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        int length = number.length();
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            //Illegal Character
            if(getValue(number.charAt(i)) == -1) { 
                return -1;
            }
            //More than 3 same Characters successively
            if(i < length - 3) { 
                if(number.charAt(i) == number.charAt(i + 1) && number.charAt(i) == number.charAt(i + 2) && number.charAt(i) == number.charAt(i + 3)) {
                    return - 1;
                }
            }

            //Applying rules
            if(i < length - 1) {
                int currentChar = getValue(number.charAt(i));
                int nextChar = getValue(number.charAt(i + 1));
                if(currentChar < nextChar) {
                    result = result + nextChar - currentChar;
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    result = result + currentChar;
                }
            }       
            else {
                result = result + getValue(number.charAt(i));
            }
        }   
        return result;
    }

    public static String arabicToRoman(int number) {
        if(number < 1 || number > 3999) {
            return "Error";
        }
        String result = "";
        int[] values = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};
        String[] romanNumerals = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};
        int i = 0;

        //Here happens the main task
        while(i < values.length) {
            if(number >= values[i]) {
                result += romanNumerals[i];
                number = number - values[i];
            }   
            else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    //Returns value of roman numeral
    private static int getValue(char c) {
        char[] array = {'I', 'V', 'X', 'L', 'C', 'D', 'M'};
        int[] arr = {1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000};
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(c == array[i]) {
                return arr[i];
            }
        }
        return -1;      
    }

    //Gets input - (1) or (2)
    private static int getInput() {
        System.out.print("Roman to Arabic (1) or Arabic to Roman (2)?");
        int decision = scanner.nextInt();
        if(decision != 1 && decision != 2) {
            return getInput();
        }
        return decision;
    }

    //gets roman number as input and checks if it only consists of roman numerals
    private static String getRoman() { 

        String number = "";

        while(!number.matches("[IVXLCDM]+")) {

            number = scanner.nextLine();
            if(!number.matches("[IVXLCDM]+")) {
                System.out.println("Enter roman number:");
            }
        }
        return number;
    }

    //gets integer between 1 and 3999 as input
    private static int getInt() {
        int number = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter number:");
        try {
            number = scanner.nextInt();             
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        if(number > 3999 || number < 1) {
            return getInt();
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

## Testing

For testing purposes I wrote the following class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Testing romanToArabic()
        boolean test1 = true;
        String[] input1 = { "", "I", "V", "XXXIII", "DCCXLVII", "CMXXIX", "MCCXXXII", "MMMCMXCIX", "MMMMXI", "KMXI"}; 
        int[] expectedOutput1 = {-1, 1, 5, 33, 747, 929, 1232, 3999, -1, -1};
        for(int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++) {
            if(RomanNumbers.romanToArabic(input1[i]) != expectedOutput1[i]) {
                test1 = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Roman to Arabic: " + test1);

        //Testing arabicToRoman()
        boolean test2 = true;
        int[] input2 = {-1, 1, 5, 33, 747, 929, 1232, 3999, 4000};
        String[] expectedOutput2 = {"Error", "I", "V", "XXXIII", "DCCXLVII", "CMXXIX", "MCCXXXII", "MMMCMXCIX", "Error"};
        for(int i = 0; i < input2.length; i++) {
            if(!(RomanNumbers.arabicToRoman(input2[i])).equals(expectedOutput2[i])) {
                test2 = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Roman to Arabic: " + test2);
    }
}
```

## Question

How can I improve both, the main-Class and the testing class?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

---

You can find the follow-up question on unit-testing [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240490/junit-unit-testing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Magic Numbers

From `main()`, we can see `getInput()` returns `1` or some other value.  What input does `getInput()` get?  What does `1` mean?  What is the other value?

Consider using named constants, such as:

```
private final static int ROMAN_TO_ARABIC = 1;
private final static int ARABIC_TO_ROMAN = 2;
```

And change `getInput()` to something more meaning full, like perhaps `getConversionDirection()`.

The variable `decision` is equally cryptic.  What decision?   Did the program decide something, or was it a command from the user and not actually a decision by the program?  Maybe `conversion_direction`, or simply `direction`.

The `if`/`else` statement would be better served by a case statement:

```
switch (conversion_direction) {
    case ROMAN_TO_ARABIC: {
        ...
    } break;
    case ARABIC_TO_ROMAN: {
       ...
    } break;
}
```

This makes it very clear what the choice is all about.

Even better: instead of named integer constants, use an `enum`:

```
public enum ConversionDirection { ROMAN_TO_ARABIC, ARABIC_TO_ROMAN };
```

## try-with-resources

Manually closing resources, like the `scanner` is tedious.  And error prone, especially when exceptions might be raised.

You should use the `try-with-resources` construct, which automatically closes resources for you.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) {
    // .... use the scanner here ...
}
// Scanner is automatically closed at this point, even if an exception is raised
```

## Too much validation

`getRoman()` can only return a string which matches `"[IVXLCDM]+"`.  This precluded `null` and the `""`.  Then, `romanToArabic()` redundantly checks for these conditions.  (Incorrectly, actually.  If `number == null`, the first part of the expression would generate a `NullPointerException` before the `null` check at the end!)  Then, each character of string is yet again tested by `getValue()` to see if it is in the set `IVXLCDM`.

## Redundant queries

The expression `number.charAt(i)` occurs 6 times inside the `while` loop.  This would be a good place to use a temporary variable at the start of the loop:

```
char ch = number.charAt(i);
```

## Insufficient validation

`IC`, `IL`, `IC`, `ID`, `IM`, `VX`, `VV`, `DD`, `XD`, `XM`, `VX`, and so on are all improper Roman numerals.  Only `I`, `X`, and `C` are legal subtractive prefixes, and only in front of `V` & `X` for `I`, `L` & `C` for `X`, and `D` & `M` for `C`.

Moreover, `IX` is valid, `XIII` is valid, but `IXIII` is not valid.  A subtractive prefix may not be followed by the same suffix, adding what was subtracted.

`getInt()` will catch any exception (it should only catch `InputMismatchException`), and clear the invalid line.  `getInput()` doesn’t catch any exception and a bad input will crash the program.

## Recursion

`getInt()` and `getInput()` recursively call themselves if out-of-range input is given.  You should use a loop, not recursion.

## Testing

Testing can be improved by leveraging the [`JUnit`](https://junit.org/junit5/) testing framework.  And adding more tests, such as the invalid cases mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just posted a follow-up question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240490/junit-unit-testing.